Why does “Reduce Protections" appear in nextjs project?
I am developing a project with Nextjs. I deploy this project to Vercel and view it from my phone. When the user logs in to the admin page, I add a "token" key to localstorage and give its value to the _id value of the newly created data in my tokens table in mongodb. When the page is refreshed, I check if there is a "token" key in localstorage with useEffect. If there is, I connect to the db and check. The user is automatically logged in.
At the same time, in this useEffect, I also pull the variable I hold for dark mode from localstorage.
I don't know if it is due to this setting or something else, but on iPhones, this panel gives the warning "If this page is not displaying as expected, you can reduce advanced privacy protections, which may resolve issues." What is the reason and solution for this?
This is the useEffect that I used to pull this data from.
useEffect(() => {
    const getFrontendData = async () => {
      const resFrontend = await axios({
        method: "get",
        url: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/frontend_settings_get`,
      });
      setFrontendSettings(resFrontend.data);
    };
    getFrontendData();
    const storedData =
      typeof window !== "undefined" && localStorage.getItem("token");
    const isTokenExpired = async (_id) => {
      try {
        const res = await axios({
          method: "post",
          url: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/auth_control`,
          data: {
            token: _id,
          },
        });
        if (res.status == 200) {
          setToken(_id);
        } else {
          localStorage.removeItem("token");
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
      setIsLoading(false);
    };
    if (storedData) {
      isTokenExpired(storedData);
    } else {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
    const localstorageDarkMode =
      typeof window !== "undefined" && localStorage.getItem("darkMode");
    if (localstorageDarkMode == "true") {
      setIsDarkMode(localstorageDarkMode);
    }
  }, []);

And this is the return codes of the page.
return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Admin Panel</title>
      </Head>
      {!isLoading && (
        <div>
          {frontendSettings !== undefined && (
            <>
              {token ? (
                <Admin
                  token={token}
                  setToken={setToken}
                  isDarkMode={isDarkMode}
                  setIsDarkMode={setIsDarkMode}
                  toggleDarkMode={toggleDarkMode}
                  frontendSettings={frontendSettings}
                />
              ) : (
                <Login
                  setToken={setToken}
                  isDarkMode={isDarkMode}
                  toggleDarkMode={toggleDarkMode}
                />
              )}
            </>
          )}
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

This is the next.config.mjs file
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    appDir: false,
  },
};

export default nextConfig;

